# How to instantiate an object in XAML with a factory method

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, uwp

The need for using async/await in a constructor leads me to a static factory method of instantiating an object. Without async/await my object is instantiated in XAML like so:

```
<viewModel:MyClass x:key="myClass"/>
```

If I use a static factory method, call it CreateAsync(), the object instantiation code looks like:

```
MyClass myClass = await MyClass.CreateAsync();
```

All is fine in code-behind and works as expected, but I want the equivalent of the above code in XAML if at all possible. A quick search suggests along the line of the following with a new attribute FactoryMethod to specify the factory method.

```
<viewModel:MyClass x:FactoryMethod="CreateAsync" x:key="myClass"/>
```

But, the catch is that x:FactoryMethod is only supported in XAML 2009 (and not XAML 2006). Furthermore, based on my brief research, XAML 2009 is not yet supported.

So, what to do to instantiate an object in XAML given a static factory method as shown above with a simple example? Is there a work-around considering that x:FactoryMethod as yet is not usable?

Comment: I am not hanging on an async constructor for its sake if there is a better route. I want data to be initialized upon binding to a data object and the initialization happens to be (and needs to be!) asynchronous. It would be ideal to do all from within XAML. I can do this from ViewModel, no problem, but thought an all-XAML solution, if at all possible is, in my opinion, more elegant. I am assuming that it should be possible to do it in XAML but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for your problem is using MVVM Light.

What you actually need from MVVM Light is the SimpleIoc class and [this](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/d989c4c0-3070-bd7d-322e-8c8fed580abf.htm) function of it.

By using this one, you can build a similar ViewModel locator that I did [here](https://github.com/uruk/OneTox/blob/e0eb379f6f6c8b2e833c7512630ddeaa9ea7d057/OneTox/Config/ViewModelLocator.cs), except you'll pass your factory method when registering your ViewModel.
After that, you can simply bind to it like I did [here](https://github.com/uruk/OneTox/blob/e0eb379f6f6c8b2e833c7512630ddeaa9ea7d057/OneTox/View/MainPage.xaml#L9).

It's clearly not exactly what you wanted to do, and is a workaround, but using IoC containers (and MVVM Light or a similar toolkit) when dealing with Windows apps is good practice anyway and the sooner you get the knack of it, the better. ;)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at your links and come back.